# R igraph indexing

Tags: r, igraph

I have some trouble executing this code:

```
library(igraph)
library('ggplot2')
subgraphz <- graph.famous("Zachary")

qq <- transitivity(subgraphz, type="local")
qq <- max(q, na.rm = TRUE)

V(subgraphz)$tr <- (transitivity(subgraphz, v=V(subgraphz), 
type="local"))
V(subgraphz)$size <- 5
V(subgraphz)[tr==qq]$size <- 15

plot(subgraphz)
```

I get this error:

> simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) :Unknown vertex selected

I expect that vertices with a maximum value of transitivity will become size 15. This is something about logical indexes but I have no idea how exactly can I fix this.

Comment: @MrFlick I've tried to do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the vertices that you want like this

```
V(subgraphz)[which(V(subgraphz)$tr==qq)]$size <- 15
plot(subgraphz)
```

[image: Zachary]